# Xamarin iOS: Auto Layout within scroll view?

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a scrollView on my storyboard on which I have added  top, left, right, bottom constraints in order for it to resize automatically in accordance with different screen sizes. The problem is that if I add image view or any other stuff within this scroll view and place constraints on this image view to maintain some distance from top, left, right and bottom of the scrollview boundaries. It just doesn't work. I Would like to have everything resized according to the screen size of the target device. How could I do so?

Light Grey area is my scrollview, grey area is plain view, innermost element is imageview.

[image]

Comment: What will happen as you do?

Comment: Hi, do you have any question?

Comment: @ColeXia I am lost.  I have upvoted your answer for your efforts. But  still somehow I am just not able to make it work. All I need to figure out is how to create a page similar to this : 

https://ibb.co/kM7Lkb

With vertical scroll but no horizontal scroll. If I could figure out how to do that I think 80% percent of my problems would be solved.

I could post it as a separate question if you would like me to.

Comment: @Arbaaz why don't you use UITableView? I think it is easier for you requirement.

Comment: Isn't UITableView used when you have to display same content multiple times? The image I have shown is just an example. I don't think UITableView would be easier since each cell will not have textbox. A page could have a combination of various elements such as textfield, dropdown, or images. All I want is to put it on a page and let the iOS auto resize the width and increase or decrease vertical scroll on its own.

Comment: Yes , when we need to display same content multiple times, UITableView  is more appropriate. I saw you want to place so many controls in the scrollview, I think you should set them in code instead of in storyboard  design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little complicated to explain.

As we know , before the `autolayout` get working, we should set constraints on them , according to those constraints the compiler can determine the `Frame` (position and size) on controls.

However, `UIScrollView` is a bit of different from `UIView`. In general, we just need to set `left,right,top,bottom` , but in `UIScrollView`, it has a definition called **contentSize** which determines the actual size of scrollview. so the constraints we set above is not enough.

So, as a workaround ,we add a **container view** inside the scrollview to determine contentSize.

#### 1. Constraint on scrollview (green area in the following gif)

[image]

#### 2. Constraint on container view.(red area in the following gif)

pay attention: we set additional width (equal to scrollview) in order to indicate the the width is fixed , means we can't scroll horizontally but vertical orientation is allowed.

[image]

#### 3. Constraint on inner view(blue area in the following gif)

[image]

#### Test result :

[image]

#### iPhone5S

[image]

#### iPad Air2

[image]

Comment: can you please add a text field in blue area. (width almost same as the blue area itself? I have been trying it but textfield gets cut off on smaller screens, which means blue area isn't resizing as it should.

Comment: @Arbaaz the blue area is the inner control you want to place，how do you set the constraint on textfield

Comment: can you please somehow share code files with me? I am unable to make it work.

Comment: I am lost. I have upvoted your answer for your efforts. But still somehow I am just not able to make it work. All I need to figure out is how to create a page similar to this : ibb.co/kM7Lkb With vertical scroll but no horizontal scroll. If I could figure out how to do that I think 80% percent of my problems would be solved. I could post it as a separate question if you would like me to.

Comment: I will mark it as soon as my problem gets solved. 
I have posted another question , perhaps you could help me with it.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642679/xamarin-ios-autolayout-resize-width-and-vertical-scroll-automatically-for-vario

Comment: Hi, I am trying to this with code instead of interface builder and I cannot get this to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713184/using-autolayout-and-uiscrollview-programatically Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I' ve encountered this question while I was struggling with this problem. The accepted answer is quite right, even if it leaves out some details.

Here I've made a complete answer will all the details,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49096334/3765617

I write it here because maybe it will be helpful for someone in the future.