# How to design an advanced UIScrollView Xamarin.ios?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I had a problem using a UIScrollView with xamarin.ios
I used the scrollView normally, and everything is going well, but the point is that I can't adjust the tools size"Constraints" inside the ScrollView, for example I have many sizes for ios phone screens, so I don't want to make a specific width and hight for tools, and that what storyboard force me to do.

any ideas, open source or tutorial.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoLayout on `UIScrollView` is different from `UIView`.

Refer to my recent answer [Auto Layout within scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488824/xamarin-ios-auto-layout-within-scroll-view/46539635#46539635) , also a demonstrative demo in the comment.

Comment: Detailed demonstration :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642679/xamarin-ios-autolayout-resize-width-and-vertical-scroll-automatically-for-vario/46664304#46664304