# Using AutoLayout and UIScrollView programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to make a copy of the answer from this question here: [Xamarin iOS: Auto Layout within scroll view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488824/xamarin-ios-auto-layout-within-scroll-view/46539635#46539635) but without using the interface builder. The code is simple, I have `_scrollView` which has background color green. Then I have `_contentView` which has background color red. I add `_contentView` to `_scrollView` and I add `_scrollView` to View in the `ViewController`. When I run this, all I get is Green controller, the red one never appears inside of it.

```
public async override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    //ui
    View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

    //views
    _scrollView = new UIScrollView();
    _scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
    _scrollView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    _contentView = new UIView();
    _contentView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    _contentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

    var label = new UILabel();
    label.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    label.Text = "Text";

    _contentView.AddSubview(label);

    _scrollView.AddSubview(_contentView);

    View.AddSubviews(new UIView[] { _scrollView });

    _scrollView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TopAnchor, 100).Active = true;
    _scrollView.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.LeftAnchor, 20).Active = true;
    _scrollView.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.RightAnchor, -20).Active = true;
    _scrollView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.BottomAnchor, -100).Active = true;

    _contentView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_contentView.Superview.TopAnchor).Active = true;
    _contentView.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_contentView.Superview.RightAnchor).Active = true;
    _contentView.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_contentView.Superview.LeftAnchor).Active = true;
    _contentView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_contentView.Superview.BottomAnchor).Active = true;
    _contentView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_contentView.Superview.WidthAnchor).Active = true;

    label.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(label.Superview.TopAnchor, 100).Active = true;
    label.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(label.Superview.BottomAnchor, 100).Active = true;
    label.LeftAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(label.Superview.LeftAnchor, 100).Active = true;
    label.RightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(label.Superview.RightAnchor, 100).Active = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to make it work was by adding BottomAnchor to the last UIView inside ContentView. I created a GitHub repo with demo code [here](https://github.com/bobekhj/Xamarin.iOS.ScrollViewAutoLayout)

Answer (score 0):

You need to constraint the width of the `_contentView` to the `View` instead of `_scrollView`. Change this constraint:

```
_contentView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(_contentView.Superview.WidthAnchor).Active = true;
```

For this one:

```
_contentView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.WidthAnchor).Active = true;
```

Other than that I highly recommend you to use a helper library for using AutoLayout programatically. Check out [FluentLayout](https://github.com/FluentLayout/Cirrious.FluentLayout)

Comment: I did a quick test and it didn't work. But I figured it out some other way. When you specify Height of any view thats inside `_contentView`, and you specify `BottomAnchor` of the last view inside `_contentView`, it magically works. It looks like it takes that last subview and it calculates the height of the `_contentView` from that `BottomAnchor`. I am going to create a sample play around with it, see if I can make your suggestion work and probably put it on GitHub because it was miserable couple hours and it might help someone in the future.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Your _contentView doesn't have any intrinsic height, you have to let it know by specifying constraints on its children. The trick of setting the _contentView width equals to the View width is there to make the scrollview scroll vertically only. If you need a scrollview to scroll horizontally, then you might tie the _contentView.Height instead of the _contentView.Width

Comment: This sample app should help you build your constraints. It uses FluentLayout but it easy to translate https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/StarWarsSample/StarWarsSample.iOS/Views/PersonView.cs#L144