# Why is the footer image not aligned to the bottom of the view?

Tags: xcode, layout, xamarin.ios, storyboard, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to use storyboard and layout constraints to align the footer image to the bottom of the view but when running on device it's hovering high above the bottom. The image is aligned with 0 margin to the superview. The view hierarchy is Controller->View->ScrollView->View->FooterImage. The image is bigger and scaled with content mode set to "aspect fit".

[image: XCode and device displayed though quicktime]

Answer (score 0):

The constraints  set on the image is sufficient, but I guess the constraints set on its super View is incorrect.

If you want to display the image at bottom you also need to make it superView align to the bottom of the `ScrollView` , and the same on ScrollView.

Check my previous answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46539635/8187800 .

Comment: @Cliffhanger Have you solved the problem ?